# stackmob ios datastore http 401 error

Tags: ios, datastore, http-status-code-401, stackmob

I'm using the iOS DataStore API to upload data to StackMob. I get this error when I try to use my smclient initialized with my public key.

```
HTTP Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 401.)" UserInfo=0xa14dac0 {error=Insufficient authorization}
```

Sample code

```
[[self.smclient dataStore] createObject:eventDictObj
                                          inSchema:@"EventSchema"
                                         onSuccess:^(NSDictionary *object, NSString *schema)
                                            {
                                                NSLog(@"Created online event : %@", object);
                                                successBlock();
                                            }
                                         onFailure:^(NSError *error, NSDictionary* object, NSString *schema)
                                            {
                                                failedBlock(error);
                                            }];
```

And smclient is initialized as follows

```
self.smclient = [[SMClient alloc] initWithAPIVersion:@"0" publicKey:@"xxxxxxxxxx"];
```

For this use case I don't need to use the logged in user credentials to create this entry in StackMob

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the permissions are set to Open on  your stack mob database.